# How handle completely different types of errors in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

What is the best way to handle completely different errors in Node js.
For example

Error1

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 at settle (C:\xxx\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1909:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\xxx\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2989:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
   code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
   config: {
     transitional: {
     silentJSONParsing: true,
       forcedJSONParsing: true,
     clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'User-Agent': 'axios/1.4.0',
       'Content-Length': '622',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
   method: 'post',
url: 'http......
```

Error2

```
Error
    at Query.run (C:\xxx\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:107:25) at xxx\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async MSSqlQueryInterface.insert (C:\xxx\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:308:21)       
    at async FulfillmentAttempt.save (C:\xxx\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2490:35)
   at async fulfillmentAttempt.create (C:\xxx\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1362:12)
    at async module.exports (C:\xxx\index.js:96:21) {
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
   errors: [
     ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'PK__Fulfillm__3213E83FF443A6B3 must be unique',
     type: 'unique violation',
       path: 'PK__Fulfillm__3213E83FF443A6B3',
      value: '1                                   ',
      origin: 'DB',
      instance: [fulfillmentAttempt],
     validatorKey: 'not_unique',
     validatorName: null,
     validatorArgs: []
   }
  ],
  parent: RequestError: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Fulfillm__3213E83FF443A6B3'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FulfillmentAttempts'. The duplicate key value is (1                               
    ).
```

Now how can I handle these error at the same time, if they are coming form the same code?
Is it possible to handle them within a single `try-catch`?